Docker build fails at RUN apt update ( ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100)
I'm trying to build a docker image from ros:humble-ros-base, on a Raspberry Pi4 with Ubuntu 22.04 installed.
The first lines of the Dockerfile are
FROM ros:humble-ros-base
RUN apt update

I get the error
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/bash -c apt update -y" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100

after reading all package lists successfully.
Tried to uninstall and reinstall docker completely, and also tried with other debian bases images, it always fails at the same point.
Also tried running
docker run --privileged --rm tonistiigi/binfmt --install all

, as suggested in another related topic, but it didn't solve the problem.
The Dockerfile builds successfully on other platforms (a computer under ubuntu 22.04 and one under 20.04).
Would anyone have an idea on what could the problem be ?
Thanks

I found out that my Raspberry's date and time were set wrong, which was apparently the source of the error.
Setting the clock correctly solved it.
